# Remove an initial commit from my master branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, gitlab-ci

I have only one commit in my remote master branch. How I can remove that single commit from my master branch.
I am able to remove any specific commit on remote branch if there are multiple commits on the branch, but here the issue is there is only one commit on the branch which we will remove, then there is nothing to push to remote branch.

Answer (score 2):

If there's only one commit normally you'd just [delete the branch](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/) and recreate it.

```
git push <remote> --delete <branch>
```

But Git won't allow you to delete the default branch (ie. master). This leaves us in a bind. A branch must reference a commit. No commit, no branch. If we can't remove the branch we can't remove the first commit.

The solution is to make a second commit, then remove the first.

1. Delete all the files locally.
2. Add whatever new files you want.
3. Commit that.
4. Do an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to remove the previous commit.
5. [Safe force push](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/).

Comment: I don't want to delete the master branch, is there any other way to delete the commit only.

Comment: @a.prateek A branch must reference a commit. No commit, no branch. Normally deleting it wouldn't be a problem because you'd immediately recreate it. But Git won't let you delete the default branch. I've updated my answer with a work around.